# svn: Restrict trunk commits to authorized users

Tags: svn, version-control

We are planning on having a policy to prevent commits to trunk. All commits must happen against branches.

What should be my approach to get this done?

Comment: How are you going to merge your branches into the trunk without committing?

Comment: You have to pardon me for my ignorance. Commits happen to branches. Merge happens between branches and trunk. That was the plan.

Comment: You merge into a working copy... you still need to commit after a merge to affect the repository.  You should probably reword your question to ask how you can restrict trunk commits to only authorized users (the release guy) and have it be read-only for most developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [svn documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html). IT says both apache and svnserve support path-based authorization. Also, from the documentation:

> **Do you really need path-based access
>   control?**
>
> A lot of administrators setting up
>   Subversion for the first time tend to
>   jump into path-based access control
>   without giving it a lot of thought.
>   The administrator usually knows which
>   teams of people are working on which
>   projects, so it's easy to jump in and
>   grant certain teams access to certain
>   directories and not others. It seems
>   like a natural thing, and it appeases
>   the administrator's desire to maintain
>   tight control of the repository.
>
> Note, though, that there are often
>   invisible (and visible!) costs
>   associated with this feature. In the
>   visible category, the server needs to
>   do a lot more work to ensure that the
>   user has the right to read or write
>   each specific path; in certain
>   situations, there's very noticeable
>   performance loss. In the invisible
>   category, consider the culture you're
>   creating. Most of the time, while
>   certain users shouldn't be committing
>   changes to certain parts of the
>   repository, that social contract
>   doesn't need to be technologically
>   enforced. Teams can sometimes
>   spontaneously collaborate with each
>   other; someone may want to help
>   someone else out by committing to an
>   area she doesn't normally work on. By
>   preventing this sort of thing at the
>   server level, you're setting up
>   barriers to unexpected collaboration.
>   You're also creating a bunch of rules
>   that need to be maintained as projects
>   develop, new users are added, and so
>   on. It's a bunch of extra work to
>   maintain.
>
> Remember that this is a version
>   control system! Even if somebody
>   accidentally commits a change to
>   something they shouldn't, it's easy to
>   undo the change. And if a user commits
>   to the wrong place with deliberate
>   malice, then it's a social problem
>   anyway, and that the problem needs to
>   be dealt with outside of Subversion.

Comment: Well, in the event that someone accidentally commits to trunk, I would like to know that. So, a hook is required in my case, irrespective of what it does :)

Answer (score 3):

You make me wonder what the use of trunk is, if you cannot commit to it. But pre-commit hooks offer a way to do this. See also [here](http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/usage/svn-govern-commit-permission.html).

1. Ensure that you have `/usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/commit-access-control.pl`. On Ubuntu, it's in the subversion-tools package.
2. Go to your repository directory, copy the `hooks/pre-commit.tmpl` script into `hooks/pre-commit` and make it executable.
3. Modify it to your tastes. I think the default is sensible.
4. Write `commit-access-control.cfg` in your repository directory. Something like this (untested):

[StackOverflow's parser seems to be broken, it needs a paragraph here]

```
[Make trunk read-only]
match = ^trunk
access = read-only
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write a simple post-commit hook.  You can use this example for guidance http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook

In your script just check the URL where they committing to and deny all transactions that modify the trunk URL

However, you need to designate a person who could merge the branches into the trunk,  your pre-commit hook should check either for master username or some other authenitcation mechanism and allow merges into the trunk

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. But, how would I run 'svn info' if I don't have the list of files?

Comment: look at the script under the link.  It looks into the incoming transaction so you will see the list of files being committed before they are actually committed